# Is there any alter way to increase the execution speed. Currently the below query taking 6 seconds to execute

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT  
         PER_CUR.DATEASSTRINGFORCLASS(PER_DATE_FROM,'GB') AS PERDATE,
         PER_NO,
         rangeutil.f_setpcdrangeperiod('M', PER_CUR.DATEASSTRINGFORCLASS(PER_DATE_FROM, 'GB')) AS PERIOD
     FROM   
         PER_W  
     WHERE  
         PERT_CODE = 'YM2' 
         AND PER_NO >= RANGEUTIL.ADDNUMPERIOD('YM2', RANGEUTIL.DATEPERIOD('YM2'), -4) 
         AND per_date_from < '02-JUN-21'
             
     UNION

     SELECT  
         PER_CUR.DATEASSTRINGFORCLASS(PER_DATE_FROM,'GB') AS PERDATE, PER_NO,
         rangeutil.f_setpcdrangeperiod('M', PER_CUR.DATEASSTRINGFORCLASS(PER_DATE_FROM,'GB')) AS PERIOD
     FROM 
         PER_W  
     WHERE  
         PERT_CODE = 'YM' 
         AND per_date_from > '01-JUN-21' 
         AND PER_NO >= RANGEUTIL.ADDNUMPERIOD('YM', RANGEUTIL.DATEPERIOD('YM'), -4))
WHERE
    per_no >= rangeutil.f_defaultPcdRangePeriod('M')
ORDER BY 
    2;
```

Comment: Probably, but just the query is not enough. What are `PER_CUR.DATEASSTRINGFORCLASS` and `rangeutil.f_setpcdrangeperiod`?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, explanation of what the query should be doing and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: PER_CUR.DATEASSTRINGFORCLASS  
FUNCTION dateasstringforclass (
      i_date        IN   DATE
     ,i_lang_code   IN   VARCHAR2
   )
      RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
      res   VARCHAR2 (20);
   BEGIN
      IF i_lang_code = 'GB' THEN
         res := INITCAP (TO_CHAR (i_date, 'MON'));
      ELSE
         res :=
            REPLACE (REPLACE (INITCAP (TO_CHAR (i_date, 'MON')), 'May'
                             ,'Maj')
                    ,'Oct', 'Okt');
      END IF;

      res := res || ' ' || TO_CHAR (i_date, 'YYYY');
      RETURN res;
   END;

Comment: @Elakkia , add that function definition to your question , also which dbms are you using?

Comment: If you provide sample data and desired output but also what is "RANGEUTIL.ADDNUMPERIOD"  paste code inside that too